# On Event Handler Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to run some JQuery when clicking on a List Item but the click event does not seem to fire when checking in debugger.

The Script is:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.range', function (event) {
            var rangeid = $(this).data('value');
            var url2 = '/Home/GetMachineTypeByRange/-1';
            url2 = url2.replace("-1", rangeid);

            $.get(url2, function (data) {
                $('#MachineTypeDropDown').html(data);
                $('#MachineTypeDropDown').toggle();
            });
        });
```

And my HTML is:

```
    <div class="button-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle col-md-12" data-toggle="dropdown">Select a product category <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul id="RangeDropDown" class="dropdown-menu col-md-12" data-url="/Home/GetRangeForCorp">
           <li class="range" data-value="1"><a href="#" class="range" data-value="1" tabindex="-1">Articulated Dump Trucks</a></li>
           ...
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="button-group" style="display: none;">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle col-md-12" data-toggle="dropdown">Select a machine type <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul style="display: none;" id="MachineTypeDropDown" class="dropdown-menu col-md-12"></ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Try just `$(document)`

Comment: Is the click handler defined inside `$( document ).ready(function() { 
});` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should work

with test code

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.range', function (event) {
            alert("test");
        });
```

look at this fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/d15czyt3/

i suspect your get is failing

Comment: please explain how you resolved your problem, to help others in the community who might face it in the future

Comment: your event is bubbling up to it's parent  `<ul>`. You could use [event.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) if that is not the intended behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Your code work "fine", the problem should be that the event is propagating to it's parent...

This solve it:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.range', function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();//-> the event execute 1 time the code!
        var rangeid = $(this).data('value');
        var url2 = '/Home/GetMachineTypeByRange/-1';
        url2 = url2.replace("-1", rangeid);

        console.log(url2 + " | " +rangeid);
        $.get(url2, function (data) {
            $('#MachineTypeDropDown').html(data);
            $('#MachineTypeDropDown').toggle();
        });
    });
```

[event.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)
, check also if url2 is getting the url you really want (if it's correct) and you may want to use post instead of get, because get to increase performance uses "web cache information"